# Knockout and observablearrays using mapping plugin

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-mvc

the below code is working fine when i call it at the first time, however in the second call the gridviewmodel becomes messy and all data become redundant

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'rest service uri',
        type: 'GET',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,

        success: function (data) {

            function gridviewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.items = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                self.columns = [
                    new column("Name", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("URL", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Embargo Date", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Status", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Reviewer Name", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Approver Name", "name", "Asc")
                ];
            };


            ko.applyBindings(new gridviewModel());
}
```

I tried to clear the observable array using removeAll() but it doesn't work with me.

### Any idea?

Just for any one may face this issue in the future i managed to fix it by call ko.mapping.fromJS(data, gridviewModel.items) in Knockout mapping plugin
Full code is

```
var gridviewModel = {

        items: ko.mapping.fromJS([]),
        columns: [
                    new column("Name", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("URL", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Embargo Date", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Status", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Reviewer Name", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Approver Name", "name", "Asc")
                ]
};

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(gridviewModel, document.getElementById("wip"));

});
```

Hope this solves others issue.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs on knockout mapping plugin,  it appears as though your mapped `data` object should be your `viewmode` instead of a property within your `viewmodel`.  If I were you i would modify my code to use the following:

```
          function gridviewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.items = data;
                self.columns = [
                    new column("Name", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("URL", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Embargo Date", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Status", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Reviewer Name", "name", "Asc"),
                    new column("Approver Name", "name", "Asc")
                ];
            };


            ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(new gridviewModel()));
```

This will map your entire object as the docs specify.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, I was missing calling the updateFromJS() method. 'code' ko.mapping.fromJS(data, gridviewModel.items);

Comment: glad you found the issue!  You introduced me to a cool plugin!  I'll be using it in the morning.  Thanks.

Comment: lots of other good leads on the mapping plugin if you search for knockout-mapping in the stack